# how to display post content without post image?

Tags: posts, images, filters

i've implemented a jQuery gallery for displaying several images within a post.
the problem is that the_content(); also displays the post image.
any ideas how to filter it?
thanks

Comment: maybe you can give us a little more to work with? Are you just attaching the images to the post or are you actually putting them in the post content?

Comment: i've attached the images directly to the post (i'm having the [gallery] tag in my content) - but as attaching images has to be easy for our customer, the tag needs to remain in the content - that's why i need to filter it at the frontend. thanks

Comment: you would still attach images per post just leave out gallery short code and write a get_posts query for attachments. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts as the `post_type` would be `attachments` and then use `wp_get_attachment_image` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) and manually build your gallery in the theme. The only difference would be the lack of `[gallery]` in your post content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can add a filter to the_content hook to strip the images

something like:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'strip_images',2);

function strip_images($content){
   return preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','',$content);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have this to work only on certain pages and not on other pages (or categories?)

Comment: Yep, just check in the function if its the right page using Conditional Tags http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 1):

This is better:

```
<?php echo strip_shortcodes(wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 80 )); ?>
```

Change 80 to whatever count words.

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.